# Multiplicate entry on update_post_meta

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I have a metabox with an array of input:

```
<input type="text" name="activite_dates[]" size="30" /><br />
<input type="text" name="activite_dates[]" size="30" /><br />
<input type="text" name="activite_dates[]" size="30" /><br />
...
```

And i'm saving it like this

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, "dates", $_POST['activite_dates'] );
```

The problem is that when i'm retrieving it I have to make a ugly function to read multiple dimension array

```
Array 
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => DATA1
        [1] => DATA2
        [2] => DATA3
        [3] => DATA99
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => DATA1
        [1] => DATA2
        [2] => DATA3
        [3] => DATA99
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => DATA1
        [1] => DATA2
        [2] => DATA3
        [3] => DATA99
    )
```

)

And when I'm saving it, it's only add to append to existent array

```
Array 
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => DATA1
        [1] => DATA2
        [2] => DATA3
        [3] => DATA99
        [4] => DATA1
        [5] => DATA2
        [6] => DATA3
        [7] => DATA99
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => DATA1
        [1] => DATA2
        [2] => DATA3
        [3] => DATA99
        [4] => DATA1
        [5] => DATA2
        [6] => DATA3
        [7] => DATA99        
     )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => DATA1
        [1] => DATA2
        [2] => DATA3
        [3] => DATA99
        [4] => DATA1
        [5] => DATA2
        [6] => DATA3
        [7] => DATA99
    )

)
```

So first, why do I have 3 value at the first level then my array is multiplied inside of the second level ?

For information here is my code for the view  :

```
$dates_gf = get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'dates', false );
foreach ($dates_gf as $date_gf) {
    if (is_array($date_gf)){
        foreach ($date_gf as $arr_date_gf) {
            ?> <input type="text" name="activite_dates_gf[]" value="<?php echo $arr_date_gf; ?>" size="30" /><br /> <?php
        }
    } else {
        ?> <input type="text" name="activite_dates_gf[]" value="<?php echo $date_gf; ?>" size="30" /><br /> <?php
    }
} ?>
```

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// Check to make sure array is ready
if( isset($_POST['activite_dates']) && is_array($_POST['activite_dates']) ) {
    // If we have an array ready to save delete all the previous data
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, "dates");
    foreach($_POST['activite_dates'] as $date) {
        // Use add post meta instead of passing the array directly in
        add_post_meta( $post_id, "dates", esc_attr($date));
    }
}



$dates_gf = get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'dates', false );

// No need for the is_array() check when using false for the $single variable. Check for empty() instead
if(!empty($dates_gf)) {
    foreach($dates_gf as $date_gf) {
        ?> <input type="text" name="activite_dates_gf[]" value="<?php echo $date_gf; ?>" size="30" /><br /> <?php
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Cole, that's worked like a charm ! I find my self stupid to haven't think this way at first !